shibboleth muti SPs need same attributes
i have to Sps(aws,aliyun) ,which needs same attributes named "name" and "role".

i configured the attribute-resolver.xml ,giv them two names "role-aws" and "role-aliyun",and refrence it in attribute-filter.xml,

and when i using aalci cmd test, then show the "attributes" ,aliyun is "name":"role-aliyun",aws is "name":"role-aws" ,but they needs the value of name should be "role",
how can i mondify attribute-resolver.xml or attribute-filter.xml to fix then,thanks!
any sps release then same props {"name":"role","value": "dymatic provide by attribute-resolve props"}
